# Difficulty with ES6 import / export syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I currently have a directory structure as follows, where + denotes a folder:

```
+ middleware
  - index.js
  + tracking
    - index.js
    + googleAnalytics
      - index.js
      - logPageView.js
      - trackPanos.js
    + mixpanelAnalytics
      - index.js
      - trackUser.js
- index.js
```

The lowest level `index.js` files in the `googleAnalytics` and `mixPanel` directories look like this:

```
--/middleware/tracking/googleAnalytics/index.js
import {logPageView} from './logPageView';
import {trackSignup} from './trackSignup';
export const googleAnalyticsMiddleware = [logPageView, trackSignup];

--/middleware/tracking/googleAnalytics/index.js
import {trackPanos} from './trackPanos';
export const mixpanelAnalyticsMiddleware = [trackPanos];
```

**For some reason I'm able to successfully import things by directly looking up the relevant file paths**. Here is the ROOT index.js:

```
--/index.js

import {mixpanelAnalyticsMiddleware} from './middleware/tracking/mixpanelAnalytics';
import {googleAnalyticsMiddleware} from './middleware/tracking/googleAnalytics';

// This works! But notice how deep I have to dig.
```

Ideally I would want something like this:

```
// This does not work!

--/index.js
import * from './middleware';

--/middleware/index.js
export * from './tracking';

--/middleware/tracking/index.js
export * from './mixpanelAnalyticsMiddleware';
export * from './googleAnalyticsMiddleware';
```

Comment: You've got some `…Middleware` suffices in that last snippet that shouldn't be there?

Comment: There is no `import * from …` syntax. Did you mean another `export * from`, or are you actually gonna use the imports in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `import * as xxx` syntax.

So, when you have

```
export const googleAnalyticsMiddleware = [logPageView, trackSignup];
export const mixpanelAnalyticsMiddleware = [trackPanos];
```

In the js file you are importing, then it would look like

```
import * as Middleware from './middleware/file/path';
// ...
Middleware.googleAnalyticsMiddleware.doSomething();
Middleware.mixpanelAnalyticsMiddleware.doSomething();
```